# JavaScript-Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not very new with regular expressions, but I haven't been able to find an adequate expression for my problem so far:

I want to check a string that a user types into a textfield.
The string has to consist of one ore more terms that are separated with a semicolon.

There are actually two types of terms:

1. The first consists of a number, followed by a hyphen and then followed by a number again, e.g. `1-4` or `22-44`
2. The second term consists of a number and a comma repeated zero or more times, e.g. `1,2` or `4,5,6`

All terms have to be concluded with a semicolon.

A valid input would be: `1-4;5,6,7;9-11;` or `1,3;4-6;8,9,10;`

I've tried so many variations but couldn't find a solution so far. My problem is that this input string may consists of any number of terms. I tried to solve this with the `OR` operator and "lookahead", respectively, but with no success.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks much,
enne

Comment: Your examples don't match your description. The first "valid input" is missing the final semicolon, and "22-44" is not "a digit followed by a hyphen...".

Comment: That's very true Kerrek, added a semicolon and changed "digit" to "number". Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should do what you need:

```
/^(?:[0-9]+-[0-9]+;|[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*;)+$/
```

Comment: This wouldn't accept `1-4;5,6,7;9-11`, his example without a terminal `;`.

Comment: @Vache - noting that the OP's requirement is ambiguous given that that example doesn't agree with the statement on the line before it that "All terms have to be concluded with a semicolon."

Comment: Good point. The description did say that **"all terms have to be concluded with a semi-colon"** so I assumed that this included the final term.

Comment: Also the OP said a term could be a number followed by ZERO or more elements separated by commas, so you need to get rid of your second to last `+`.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: The first question looked the semicolons were separators, now it shows them as terminators.

Here is a sequence of one or more terms, *terminated* by semicolons, in which each term is either a number or a number range or a list of comma-separated numbers:

```
/^(\d+(-\d+|(,\d+)*)?;)+$/
```

With non-capturing groups

```
/^(?:\d+(?:-\d+|(?:,\d+)*)?;)+$/
```

Comment: Very cool Ray, thanks :) Unfortunately, I can only set one answer as accepted answer :/

Answer (score 1):

my take..

`^(?:\d+-\d+(?:;|$)|(?:\d+(?:[,;]|$))+)+$`

Comment: Not bad, just the last semicolon of the last term is missing. Thanks for your help.